# I am trying to open the pickle file in Flask but getting an error

Tags: machine-learning, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pickle, flask-login

Here's my sample code in app.py
I have imported all the libraries for login authentication and pickle but getting an error

app = Flask(**name**)

model1=pickle.load(open('Stocks1.pkl','rb'))

prediction=model1.predict(Stock_name)

if **name** == '**main**':
app.run(debug=True)
After running this code I am getting the error

And the error is:
line 1604, in open
raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
I wanted my pickle file to open but for some some reason it isn't loading